# CDF of two random variables

Tags: probability

Show that if $X,Y$ are random variables such that $X=Y$, then $F_X=F_Y$
Show that the inverse is false, if $F_X=F_Y\not\Rightarrow$$X=Y$.

The first I did: $F_X(a)=P(X\leq a)=P(Y\leq a)=F_y(a)$ since $X=Y$
my problem is with the second proof, I tried to find a counterexample but could't, or try to do it by contradiction, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ has uniform distribution over $[-1,1]$ then also $-X$ had uniform distribution over $[-1,1]$.

So their CDF's are the same, but $X\neq -X$ .

Answer (score 0):

You could take the pair $(X,Y)$ to be uniformly distributed on the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1].$ Then $\Pr(X=Y)=0$ but $F_X=F_Y.$